# Gitlab Pipeline to run only when MR is created

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a simple request for which I was not expecting to spend over 5mins. 2hrs into it and I still don't have a clear answer.

I just need to run a Gitlab pipeline when a MR is created. I have been through numerous documentations and whatever I am trying doesn't seem to work.

Here is the first thing I tried:

```
image: node:18.16.1-alpine

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - test

mypipeline:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "hello"
  only:
  - merge_requests
```

Doesn't work. Pipeline thinks there's nothing to run when I create the MR.

Someone please help me out here. Quite frustrating to be jumping through hoops for something that should be quite simple.

Comment: What version of Gitlab and Runner do you use?

Comment: My Gitlab is: 15.6.2 and the runners are on: 16.3.0. We are planning to Gitlab to version 16 soon as well.

Comment: Can you execute your pipeline manually?

Comment: Yes. I have the same pipeline working in other places (manual and automated)